# How to get all AWS resources connected to given AWS ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ENI and I want to know if it's connected to any AWS resources. If it's not, then I can be sure I can remove it.

When I look into the ENI, I can know it's attached to something:

1. IN AWS console, 'Network interface status' says its' 'In-use'
2. IN AWS CLI, I can find an attachment to someting

   - `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-.... --region ap-northeast-2`

**But I can't locate the EXACT reource to which the ENi is connected.** AWS CLI API's expected result includes "instance-id" attribute but mine doesn't have that field.

**How can I know the exact resource attached by the ENI?**

Comment: Kindly share the output when executing the command aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces for the ENI ?

Answer (score 0):

ENI can be attached to resources other than EC2. e.g., Lambda function, NAT GW, Load Balancer, etc.

Unfortunately, there is no one-size-fits-all CLI command that will solve this.

I will list some examples for a selection of resources:

**Lambda**

`aws lambda list-functions --region ap-northeast-2`

**NAT GW**

`aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --region ap-northeast-2`

**ELB**

`aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --region ap-northeast-2`

`aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --load-balancer-arn LOAD_BALANCER_ARN --region ap-northeast-2`

`aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn TARGET_GROUP_ARN --region ap-northeast-2`

**RDS**

`aws rds describe-db-instances --region ap-northeast-2`

**Elasticache**

`aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --region ap-northeast-2`

Each of these commands will contain an ENI id as a value under different properties (e.g., `NatGatewayAddresses` for NAT GW, `VpcSecurityGroups` for RDS, `CacheSecurityGroups` for Elasticache)